# Disable friendly_id on specific action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm using the friendly_id gem (Rails 3.2) and I want a specific action (edit) to not use the friendly id slug. How can i do this?

Example:

```
for show action: "site.com/object/friendly_id"
for edit action: "site.com/object/id/edit"
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `object` send `id` as a parameter with path, for example, use this, for edit

```
edit_user_path(@user.id)
```

for show,

```
user_path(@user)
```